# Time series_Calculation of monthly rolling average

Tags: r, time-series

How do we calculate monthly rolling average? I have monthly 2 years of data . I know that if it is 2 months rolling average ,we need to take the average of every 2 months . But since I need monthly rolling average,I am assuming that it would just be the mean of each month and prepare a chart having means of each month . Please correct me if I am wrong..
I need to show this in R.

Comment: Is your data on a daily basis or a monthly basis? Do you have 24 numbers from 2 years of monthly data and you want to compute a *one month* rolling average? Its just the data. But if you have 2*365 **daily** numbers then its a rolling mean computed every day for a two-month window. But what exactly is two months from 31st of January? Is that your basic problem?

Comment: My data is monthly. Yes.. I have 24 months of data. Generally we hear 3 week rolling average where we take average for 3 weeks and this will be continued for the new data too.Similarly for 2 months rolling average we take every 2 consecutive months and get their average. If I just say 'monthly rolling average' instead of 2-month or 5- month rolling average, what does that mean?

Comment: If you say it, you should know what it means. I suspect it means "one month rolling average", which by construction from the definition of "N-month moving average" for monthly data is... just the data.

Comment: Yes.. it is one month rolling average.

Answer (score 1):

If the 24 monthly measurements are:

```
 data = c(5,4,6,7,6,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3)
```

then the monthly rolling averages are....

```
 ra_data = I(data)
 ra_data
 #  [1] 5 4 6 7 6 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3
```

Comment: Yes.. thank you.. Even I was thinking the same.  If I had daily data for 24 months.. then in that case , each months average would be my monthly rolling average right since I am just considering monthly.

Comment: If you had daily data then a monthly rolling average *of the daily data* would be an average of about the next 30 to 31 days computed every day. You'd get 365 of them per year, and it would be smoothing the data.